# A way to get best_in_place working on ios

Tags: rubygems, best-in-place

The best_in_place gem is amazing.  We got inline editing working great for PCs and Android devices but it doesn't seem to work on iOS devices.  On iOS, it just doesn't ever activate on click.  Is there a way to get it to work on iOS?